# Disable USB 3.0 per boot

Tags: centos6, usb-flash-drive, usb-boot

CentOS 6.X does not support the option to boot off of a live USB. The issue is that not always am I able to disable the 3.0 port in BIOS. Is there any way of configuring CentOS to only use USB 3.0 on boot or not use USB 3.0 at all? (Ideally I would like to load USB 3.0 drivers once the device boots).

TIA

Comment: Wait, what? This does not follow. What is the problem you are having?

Comment: CentOS 6.X can not boot a Live-CD that is on a USB drive that is connected to a USB 3.0 port.